# Auto creation of database tables using JDO

Tags: mysql, jdo, datanucleus

I am new to JDO and MySQL. In my project, i want that all entities should be converted in table automatically.

I had start using the JDO and defined properties like this,

```
javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactoryClass=org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory


datanucleus.autoCreateSchema=true
datanucleus.validateTables=false
datanucleus.validateConstraints=false
datanucleus.query.sql.allowAll = true

javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/db_name
javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName=user
javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword=123456
javax.jdo.option.Mapping=hsql
```

Sample entity:

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION, table = "heartbeat")
public class HeartBeat implements Serializable{
    @PrimaryKey
    @Column(length=128)
    private String userId;
.......
}
```

Now, when i compile or run my application the tables are not being auto created. I am not sure which property i should use for auto creation of tables based on the entities created.

Please bear with my question as i am new to JDO and MySQL integration.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the user `user` identified by the password `123456` has sufficient privileges to create a schema and it's tables ? Try using the `root` user and see what happens.

Comment: What is your progress so far ?

Answer (score 0):

For JDO, if you want to create the schema for "tables" during the persistence process you tell DataNucleus by using this property, **datanucleus.schema.autoCreateTables**.
To auto create "columns" use **datanucleus.schema.autoCreateColumns**, and for "constraints" use **datanucleus.schema.autoCreateConstraints**. Set the properties to true.

`<property name="datanucleus.schema.autoCreateTables" value="true"/>
<property name="datanucleus.schema.autoCreateColumns" value="true"/>
<property name="datanucleus.schema.autoCreateConstraints" value="true"/>`

Shortcut for the three, use **datanucleus.schema.autoCreateAll** and set to true.

`<!-- shortcut for the three -->
<property name="datanucleus.schema.autoCreateAll" value="true"/>`

You can check the documentations here http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_4_1/jdo/schema.html

Defined your JDO properties like this;

`datanucleus.schema.autoCreateTables=true
datanucleus.schema.autoCreateColumns=true
datanucleus.schema.autoCreateConstraints=true`

or shortcut

`datanucleus.schema.autoCreateAll=true`